# How to make bottomNavigationBar notch transparent

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I want to make the notch margin spacing (space between FAB's sides and bottom bar) like android material design explain in [Inset FAB](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom/#behavior), It looks like a zoom background text in this small visible round portion. How we can make notching space transparent to see the text behind it?
However, mine bottom bar is not showing like that

[image: the desired notch design a visible text behind the bottom bar]

[image: my bottombar design]

My implementation

```
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    child: Image.asset("images/paw.png"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Map()));
    },
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
    color: Utiles.primary_bg_color,
  ),
  body: Container(...)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need `extendBody: true` in `Scaffold`

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text('text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text ');
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 12,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

[image: inset FAB]

Comment: Good to note: Remove the SafeArea form your body or this won't work!

Comment: @Lorence Cramwinckel I'd upvote your answer a few times if i could.

Comment: `SafeArea(bottom:false,)` if you still need a `SafeArea`, but want `body:` to flow under notched FAB.

Comment: @Baker Scaffold extended true results your's content to be hidden below the navigationBar and i think it's not suitable.

Answer (score 42):

## BottomAppBar + BottomNavigationBar

The question title asks about `BottomNavigationBar` so I'm adding this answer to help people using both a `BottomAppBar` *with* a `BottomNavigationBar`.

If you're ***not*** using `BottomNavigationBar`, ignore this.

#### NavBar Covers Notch

By default, a `BottomNavigationBar` used as a child inside a `BottomAppBar`, will cover the notch like so:

[image: BottomNavBar in BottomAppBar]

We need to remove its color & shadow to let the notch show.

### Using `BottomNavigationBar` in `BottomAppBar`

To keep the notch visible...

`BottomNavigationBar` needs:

- a `backgroundColor` specified, with 0 alpha (completely transparent)

  - otherwise, the default `onBackground` theme color is used, covering the notch
- `elevation: 0` to remove an ugly shadow under `BottomNavigationBar`

  - the transparent `backgroundColor` makes the shadow visible & horrendous

`BottomAppBar` needs:

- `shape: CircularNotchedRectangle()` obviously, to have a notch for the FAB
- `elevation: 0` to remove a slight shadow under the notched FAB (barely visible)

`Scaffold` needs:

- `extendBody: true` to allow body content to flow underneath notched FAB

`SafeArea` needs:

- if using `SafeArea`, use `bottom:false` arg, so our body can flow below past the `BottomNavigationBar`, under the FAB

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      extendBody: true, // CRITICAL for body flowing under FAB
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottom: false,
        // ↑ SafeArea(bottom:false) allows Scaffold body:+extendBody: to hit bottom edge
      ),
      // ↓ Location: centerDocked positions notched FAB in center of BottomAppBar ↓
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar( // ****** APP BAR ******************
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), // ← carves notch for FAB in BottomAppBar
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withAlpha(255),
        // ↑ use .withAlpha(0) to debug/peek underneath ↑ BottomAppBar
        elevation: 0, // ← removes slight shadow under FAB, hardly noticeable
        // ↑ default elevation is 8. Peek it by setting color ↑ alpha to 0
        child: BottomNavigationBar( // ***** NAVBAR  *************************
          elevation: 0, // 0 removes ugly rectangular NavBar shadow
          // CRITICAL ↓ a solid color here destroys FAB notch. Use alpha 0!
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withAlpha(0),
          // ====================== END OF INTERESTING STUFF =================
          selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined,
                    size: 40,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
                label: 'Home'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm,
                    size: 40,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
                label: 'Edit')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

#### Result

With the above pieces in place you should see something like this:

[image: BottomNavBar in BottomAppBar /w Notched FAB]

Comment: Great answer - fyi you can use Colors.transparent instead of a color with alpha set to 0.

Comment: I have to add `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` in `BottomAppBar` so that it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me a lot...
To show notch below content.
mainly we need to keep extendBody: true in Scaffold and bottom: false to SafeArea.

Comment: What an answer. All possibilities and combinations included. +1 for that.

Comment: For a recent version, the code above will overflow at the `BottomNavigationBarItem`, so to avoid that, I had to add `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` to `BottomAppBar`.

Answer (score 7):

Use, `extendBody: true`

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html),

> extendBody: true ensures that that scaffold's body will be visible through the bottom navigation bar's notch

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
 return Scaffold( 
     extendBody: true,
    (...)
```

after

```
  body: SafeArea(
         bottom: false,
    (...)
```

after "no add backgroundColor"

```
  BottomNavigationBar(
      //backgroundColor:
```

Comment: Scaffold  extended true results your's content to be hidden below the navigationBar and i think it's not suitable.

Comment: Thank you. My designer was killing me for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use safe Area ,then extended Body and probably other methods doesn't work. So set the safe Area  to  (false).