# Flutter - Create Button (or other widget) between Tabs

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I am new to flutter, I want to create a Bottom TabBar with a rounded button in the center of the tabs. Like this.

[image]

This is the only widget I have right now.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Tabbar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Tabbar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Tabbar> createState() => _TabbarState();
}

class _TabbarState extends State<Tabbar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // bottom: ,
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: Colors.blue[900],
          child: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.query_stats)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.update)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            // Text('Temporary'),
            Icon(Icons.flight, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.settings, size: 350),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

This is my output right now.

[image]

Comment: You can check [notch  bottomNavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59455684/10157127) if not, try creating custom widget widget instead of defaultTabBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try floatingActionButton and center it.

Comment: That works, any idea how to give a gap, so the button got it's own space? Thanks in advance. https://i.ibb.co/RCrLgMx/image.png

Comment: if I were you I would put it in a container and give the container white background color with some boxShadow to make it nicer, and please don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: Ahh okay, thx. And next time on other question, maybe you should provide more detailed answer and example, it's for the best. let's just say this one is off the hook. Goodluck for your next contribution.