# Creating a custom-shaped bottom navigation bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and need assistance with creating a custom-shaped bottom navigation bar. I want to achieve a unique visual design for the bottom navigation bar in my app.
To provide clarity, I have attached a screenshot of the desired custom-shaped bottom navigation bar:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, guidance, or code samples on how to create a custom-shaped bottom navigation bar in Flutter. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin to create a bottom bar like your image https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar

example:-

```
Scaffold(
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //params
   ),
   floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
   bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
      icons: iconList,
      activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
      gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
      notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.softEdge,
      onTap: (index) => setState(() => _bottomNavIndex = index),
      //other params
   ),
);
```

Comment: But, how can we make it floating

Comment: then don use the bottom navigation bar use the floating action button

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it
You need to set extendBody: true in Scaffold

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text('text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text ');
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 12,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

This answer don't belongs to me, here is the orignal post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59457307/22228906