# Achieve a custom bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve the design for the bottom navigation bar attached to this message in flutter but it is really stressing me out. I have tried different packages and solutions but i haven't made any progress yet. If anyone can be of help, i will be very delighted.
[image]

Comment: you can find by `notched shaped bottomnavbar`

Comment: Please, i don't get the your explanation. @Md.YeasinSheikh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455684/how-to-make-bottomnavigationbar-notch-transparent The question has been already answered here

Comment: @AkshitTyagi that is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldnt find any completely premade solutions to this problem, but there is a package that provides a good starting point: https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar

Once you install this you will need to edit the ...\src\convex_shape.dart in the package since the radius option only applies to the top left and right by default.

In the file above change to this

```
return radius > 0
    ? (Path()
      ..moveTo(host.left, host.top + radius)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(host.left + radius, host.top), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(p[0].dx, p[0].dy)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[1].dx, p[1].dy, p[2].dx, p[2].dy)
      ..arcToPoint(
        p[3],
        radius: Radius.circular(notchRadius + 10),
        clockwise: true,
      )
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[4].dx, p[4].dy, p[5].dx, p[5].dy)
      ..lineTo(host.right - radius, host.top)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(host.right, host.top + radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.bottom - radius)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(host.right - radius, host.bottom), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(host.left + radius, host.bottom)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(host.left, host.bottom - radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..close())
    : (Path()
      ..moveTo(host.left, host.top)
      ..lineTo(p[0].dx, p[0].dy)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[1].dx, p[1].dy, p[2].dx, p[2].dy)
      ..arcToPoint(
        p[3],
        radius: Radius.circular(notchRadius + 10),
        clockwise: true,
      )
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[4].dx, p[4].dy, p[5].dx, p[5].dy)
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.top)
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.bottom)
      ..lineTo(host.left, host.bottom)
      ..close());
```

from this

```
    return radius > 0
    ? (Path()
      ..moveTo(host.left, host.top + radius)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(host.left + radius, host.top), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(p[0].dx, p[0].dy)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[1].dx, p[1].dy, p[2].dx, p[2].dy)
      ..arcToPoint(
        p[3],
        radius: Radius.circular(notchRadius),
        clockwise: true,
      )
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[4].dx, p[4].dy, p[5].dx, p[5].dy)
      ..lineTo(host.right - radius, host.top)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(host.right, host.top + radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.bottom)
      ..lineTo(host.left, host.bottom)
      ..close())
    : (Path()
      ..moveTo(host.left, host.top)
      ..lineTo(p[0].dx, p[0].dy)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[1].dx, p[1].dy, p[2].dx, p[2].dy)
      ..arcToPoint(
        p[3],
        radius: Radius.circular(notchRadius),
        clockwise: true,
      )
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[4].dx, p[4].dy, p[5].dx, p[5].dy)
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.top)
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.bottom)
      ..lineTo(host.left, host.bottom)
      ..close());
```

After that it's as simple as providing padding, elevation, and borderRadius to customize to your liking

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Custom  bottom nav bar',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: ConvexAppBar(
          elevation: 5,
          height: 80,
          cornerRadius: 12,
          style: TabStyle.fixedCircle,
          items: const [
            TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.map, title: 'Discovery'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.add, title: 'Add'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.message, title: 'Message'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.people, title: 'Profile'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is the result of the above page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2d6e.png)

Comment: Thank you @KirkC. I will implement it and report back to you.

Comment: it works perfectly fine. I guess i have to create a package out of it using the Convex bottom bar package. If i may ask, how did you reduce the space at the bottom of the navbar? From the result you shared, the space at the bottom looks smaller compared to what i have.

Comment: Replacing the Container wrapping ConverAppBar with BottomAppBar solves the issue of the bottom space. Thank you @KirkC.

Comment: @EmmanuelNartey Glad to hear your got it sorted. YW, I've only been using Flutter/Dart for the past few months so trying to solve things like this is a good chance to learn.

Comment: Welcome to the Flutter/Dart family.