# Bottom navigation bar is floating on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

My bottom navigation is malformed when I run my Flutter app on iOS. It seems to be floating:

[image]

My scaffold looks like this:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: getAppbar(),
  drawer: getMainDrawer(context),
  floatingActionButton: ...,
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  body: SafeArea(
    top: false,
    bottom: false,
    child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
  ),
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar())
```

My bottom navigation looks like this:

```dart
Widget buildBottomNavigationBar() {
  return BottomAppBar(
    key: const Key('bottomAppBar'),
    shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    elevation: 4,
    notchMargin: 8,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.dumbbell),
          label: 'Sets',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar),
          label: 'Timeline',
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
}
```

Note that the bottom navigation looks fine on Android. Does anyone know what causes this on iOS?

Comment: issue seems to be safeArea widget, try removing it,

Comment: By default, the BottomNavigationBar will cover the notch on the BottomAppBar. I think a good reference would be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67767570/6891637).

Comment: @AjilO. The issue I am trying to fix is the fact the the navigation bar is floating. The notch does not concern me as of now (the notch works when I run the above provided code so I think that it will be fine once the other issue is resolved)

Comment: @RamGupta removing the SafeArea has no effet :(

Comment: Scaffold has SafeArea by default, remove the duplicate one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out @Ajil O. was correct after all. This bug was indeed caused by the notch effect. To fix it you have to set the elevation everywhere to 0.

This code works both on iOS and Android now:

```dart
Widget buildBottomNavigationBar() {
  return BottomAppBar(
    key: const Key('bottomAppBar'),
    shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    // Note: elevation has to be zero
    elevation: 0,
    notchMargin: 8,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      // Note: elevation has to be zero
      elevation: 0,
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.dumbbell),
          label: 'Sets',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar),
          label: 'Timeline',
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `BottomAppBar` like this

```
Widget buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
          label: 'Sets',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
          label: 'Timeline',
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: _onItemTapped(),
    );
  }
```